# How do you format a logarithm's base in Stack Exchange?

Tags: notation

How would you type `log [base] (4)` in stack exchange?

Comment: $\log_4(4)$...\log_4(4) in dollar signs

Comment: Is it the correct place to ask this question?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117

Comment: Thank you that will be very usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$\log_2 4$` converts to $\log_2 4$

Comment: Thank you big, I now know where to go to find out how to format for Math Jax